# How to grant save dashboard permission in OpenSearch Dashboards

Tags: security, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I want to provide a user e.g. an analyst a set of permissions that will allow him to:

1. read index
2. build dashboard around it
3. save dashboard

First two activities are easily covered by the permissions I found (using cluster_composite_ops_ro and indices:data/read/*), however I'm still unable to define exact permissions to allow saving the dashboard. Could you please advise?

I tested all indices:data/write/* permissions, kibana_all_write cluster permissions and write action permission to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `dashboards` role that out of the box comes with the following permissions:

```
cluster permissions: cluster_monitor
index pattern: *
permissions: index, read
index pattern: .kibana*
permissions: write
```

The role had to be assigned to global_tenant and that did the trick.

Comment: Adding these just worked for me as well! Do you know which one of those exactly allows the user to save a dashboard?

Comment: Hi Sam, I only worked with generic "write" permission and it consists of multiple ones at the cluster/index level so I'm not able to tell you exactly which standalone permission it is

Answer (score 0):

there is a predefined role that you can consider: `opensearch_dashboards_user`
https://opensearch.org/docs/1.2/security-plugin/access-control/users-roles/#predefined-roles

Comment: I saw this in the documentation however there is no `opensearch_dashboards_user` in my roles list. I checked it on my production cluster 2.3.0 as well as brand new 2.5.0 sandbox. I have most of the predefined roles there but this one is missing